# Android viewpager with DepthPageTransformer z-index issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation

I implemented a viewpager with a DepthPageTransformer , in pages I have some inputs ( radio , check boxs , select options ... ). It works fine except one wired bug: Sometimes when I click on position(x,y) on a page P1  the input in that position of page P2 gets triggered.

P1:

[image: page P1]

P2( the one after P1):

[image: P2 the page after p1]

Now when I click on this position on page P1 :

[image]

I get the select options displayed of page P2:

[image]

It's similar to z-index problem in web development.

The code of the DepthPage Transformer is the same as in the documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer.

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this overlapping problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
    view.setAlpha(0);

} else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
    // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
    view.setAlpha(1);
    view.setTranslationX(0);
    view.setScaleX(1);
    view.setScaleY(1);
    // -------- THIS LINE ---
    view.bringToFront();
    // -------- THIS LINE ---

} else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
    // Fade the page out.
    view.setAlpha(1 - position);

    // Counteract the default slide transition
    view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

    // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
    float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
            + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

} else { // (1,+Infinity]
    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
    view.setAlpha(0);
}
}
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and reprt back to you ASP , thank you for taking the time and answering :)

Comment: `ViewPager` is depricated now . The only I did here was to replace it with new 
 ViewPager2

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reverse draw order:

```
        mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
```

In any case you can play with code sample [here](https://github.com/dlykoits/ViewPagerTransformerBug)

Comment: Bingo! Best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is use OnPageChangeListener:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }
    @Override public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        pager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pagerAdapter.getItem(position).getView().bringToFront();
            }
        }, 300);
    }
    @Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
});
```

is more efficient.

Comment: how this is more efficient than the first one ?

Comment: In first way view.bringToFront() calls every time when transformPage is invoked. This may be 10 times or more. I tested this on android 4.1 and sometimes layout is blinking. When call in onPageSelected looks ok.